# Is it possible to disable service listing in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Seems like after installing [WSO2 Enterprise Integrator](https://wso2.com/integration), by default when someone navigates to http://serverip:port/services/ all the deployed services (including those secured with a security policy) and their available operations are being listed. each service is then accessible by http://server:port/services/service_name?wsdl

Is it possible to disable this listing for all or at least for secured services? Also is it possible to disable the public access to wsdl of secured services?

I've tried adding `<parameter name="disableServiceList">true</parameter>` to axis2.xml file with no success.

Comment: IMHO the ESB is not to be directly exposed to external environment, you will need some other way to control access to individual services (api, firewall, proxy,..). As well you can enable service security where appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to disable service listing, you should set the following property in `nhttp.properties`.

```
http.block_service_list=true
```

For more information, refer : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Tuning+the+HTTP+Transport

However, unfortunately, there is no way to stop accessing the wsdl of the service if the service URL is known.

Comment: this is blocking the service list for when using the nhttp transport right? seems not working with the default pass through transport. is it possible with the pass through transport?

Comment: It does work with passthru transport. I have verified this with ESB. Could you please double check? Alternatively, try setting the same property at passthru-http.properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer maheeka. I can confirm I have tested this again and it is not working for passthru in EI-6.1.1. It is working for nhttp tho. I have decided to use [Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to control access to service listing, service wsdl, access to each service individually and everywhere else that I might need to control access. Do you think this will have any significant impact on server performance?

Comment: Update: well I was setting the property in passthru-http.properties with no luck. however when I set it in nhttp.properties it is working for passthru as well and the service listing is blocked successfully. I wonder why passthru is reading the property from nhttp.properties but thanks for your guidance this fixed the issue. Now I am facing another issue.. Do you mind taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135930/timeout-in-retrieving-the-wso2ei-service-wsdl-from-php-on-pass-through-transport) and explain the question asked in Update section? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way not to display the wsdl on request for `?wsdl`: If you leave in your proxy, choose only the https option and remove the http, then the wsdl will not be displayed for the https call and the service will be secured with https.